# O servidor Web está configurado para não listar o conteúdo deste diretório

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Meu projeto rodava tranquilamente, quando precisei dividi-los em Áreas. Então todo o meu controller antigo (que rodava perfeitamente) foi migrado para uma determinada Área. Foi mapeado as áreas e inclusive atualizado o RouteConfig. Porém, está dando este erro.

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   O servidor Web está configurado para não listar o conteúdo deste diretório.

Sabem como posso solucionar sem ter que alterar permissões específicas no diretório? Tipo, apenas ajustando o projeto no visual studio.

**Área Criada:** "Geral"
**URL:** Controller: "Principal" / Action: "Index"

```
Meu RouteConfig está assim:
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "Areas/Geral/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Principal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Qual a URL que está tentando acessar? Qual o nome das áreas que criou? Qual o nome do controller que deve receber a requisição? Ele está dentro de qual área?

Comment: jbueno, veja se a atualização que fiz responde sua pergunta.

Comment: E qual é a URL que dá este erro 403?

Comment: Seria a URL já de inicio.  `http://localhost:51454/` onde está configurada no route config para `Controller: "Principal" ,  Action: "Index"`

Comment: Tentou ? defaults: new { area = "Geral", controller = "Principal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

Comment: LP.Gonçalves, dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: @BrunoHeringer Faltou definir a area no default

Comment: blz... até consegui evoluir, mas agora o erro dá que "The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Login/Index.cshtml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para deixar registrado a solução aqui:
Meu MapRoute precisou ficar assim (com o .DataTokens):

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { area = "Geral", controller = "Principal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Geral");
```

e assim:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Geral_default",
                "Geral/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "Geral", controller = "Principal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando IIS como servidor, realizei a seguinte solução: nas propriedades de depuração do seu projeto realize o passo a passo abaixo.

1. Vá até as propriedades do seu projeto
2. Clique em Depurar
   2.1 Perfil: IIS Express
   2.2 Iniciar: IIS

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).